# LuceneNet not able to create *.fdt/*.cfs or *.fdx/*.cfx files on windows server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, lucene.net

I've a MVC ASP.NET application which builds a search index on startup with LuceneNet. On my local workstation everything is working correctly, Lucene creates all files it needs. After publishing my Website on a windows server (exactly Small Business Server 2011) and requesting the website, only the segment files are created. I'm using `"C:\Temp\LuceneIndex"` as directory. Do I need some extra permission to the folder or have I missed something?

Thanks in advance!

**Problem Fixed**

*In my solution there is also a REST-Service, as seperate project. After publishing the rest service everything works fine.*

Answer (score 0):

In windows server the default security restrictions are more limited than on a workstation. You would need to allow NETWORK SERVICE write access to c:\temp, or run your app-pool as a specific user that you grant access to.

However, you should get a security exception, and it shouldn't be able to create any files at all.

Comment: Hi jishi! I tried my app as **NETWORK SERVICE**, **ApplicationPoolIdentity**, as a specific **User** and even as **Admin**. Nothing helped me. Nethertheless you're absolutely right and that is what it makes me confused. If I have no rights to write in this directory why is my app able to create the two segement files `segments.gen`, `segments_1` and the `write.lock` file?

Comment: if the write.lock file is there, then it has started indexing. If that doesn't disappear, I would guess that your indexing crashes severely, or hasn't finished. the segments files are created directly when you create your IndexWriter, so even if you haven't indexed any documents they would be there.